# Is val a type of variable in Scala?

Tags: scala

I understand the difference between val and var in Scala. My question is would val be considered a type of variable, immutable type, in Scala still? Some online resources do consider val as different type of variable while others do not.

Comment: Variables declared with `val` and `var` are all variables (even though `val`s don't vary, per se)

Comment: Can you show some examples of such online resources? I don't think I've ever heard anyone say `val`s aren't variables

Comment: I think the problem is the definition of the word _"variable"_ for some a variable is something that changes: _" a symbolic name associated with a value and whose associated value may be changed"_. For others it just means something to which a value will be assigned upon evaluation: _"a symbol that represents a quantity in a mathematical expression"_ - [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable).

Comment: It's recommended to first read documentation and tutorials

Comment: What is your definition of "variable"? The answer to your question depends on that definition.

Answer (score 4):

Types are `Int`, `String`, `Boolean`, `List[Double]`, ...

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html

Value `x` in `val x: Int` and variable `x` in `var x: Int` are different "sorts" of identifiers with the same type `Int`.

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions